# Aspnet5 Console Application not allowing me non static main

Tags: dnx

I am developing a console application in ASPNET5. I read that it allows instance based entry point (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn913182.aspx). However when I create a new project using ASPNet5 Console Application project template, it creates public static void Main(string[] args)

Then I thought, okay I might be able to change this to non static and add dependencies in Program constructor. I tried that but it complains and says "Program does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point".

Now question is if it doesn't allow how can I inject dependencies in entry point? I am using 1.0.0-rc1-final.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Non-static Main is no longer supported in RC1. Take a look at [this](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/113) announcement for more details. You need to use `PlatformServices` and `CompilationServices` instead.

Comment: could you please share some examples of PlatformServices and CompilationServices to inject dependencies in program / main?

Comment: @Rohit - because DI is no longer auto injected if you are not using Startup class then you need to take care of it on your own. I think you should be able to create an DI container instance on your own and pass it where you need it.